# How can I express 10 milliseconds using timeval?

Tags: c, unix

How can I express 10 milliseconds using timeval?

This is what I have so far:

```
struct timeval now;
now.tv_usec =10000;
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A `struct timeval` represents a time as a number of seconds (`tv_sec`) plus a number of microseconds (`tv_usec`) between 0 and 999,999.  Thus, to represent 10 milliseconds, you would use 10,000 microseconds, as you suggested:

```
struct timeval tv;
tv.tv_sec = 0;
tv.tv_usec = 10000;
```

Comment: Just a small point. According to http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Elapsed-Time.html the tv_usec value is always less than one million, i.e. between 0 and 999,999. Otherwise you could represent a second in both the tv_sec and tv_usec fields, which doesn't make sense according to their definiton.

Comment: @binarybob good point, not so small actually if you have to allocate char buffer of correct size for microseconds

Answer (score 15):

For a more general case to convert milliseconds to timeval struct use:

```
int milliseconds = 10;
struct timeval now;
now.tv_sec = milliseconds / 1000;
now.tv_usec = (milliseconds % 1000) * 1000;
```

Answer (score 5):

it's

```
 struct timeval {
    int tv_sec;    // seconds 
    int tv_usec;   // microseconds!
```

so now.

```
tv_sec = 0;
tv_usec = 10000;
```

`
would be right

Comment: Except that the tv_sec field is (probably) uninitialized and hence likely not zero. It would be safer to set it explicitly to zero so that the intent is clear.

Comment: But, in this case, tv_sec would not be properly initialized, which may create problems. Either memset() or assign zero to tv_sec.